# Send Multiple Values of Dropdowns using Single Submit button

Tags: java, forms, jsp, submit, dropdown

I'm trying to make a form that looks like this. Each row has two drop downs: The first is select only one, and the other is select multiple. [Here is the output screen.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FTdXs.png)

From this screen, I want to send the values of all the rows (including both the drop downs) to a servlet (Testing.java) using a single submit button. In Testing.java, I basically want to be able to access all the values of each row corresponding to each Test name.

Here is my JSP code for the output shown in the imageimage:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" import = "java.util.*" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery chosen utils/chosen.css">  
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery chosen utils/welcomestyle.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div align = center>
            <table style="width: 100%">
                <tr>
                    <th> Script Name </th>
                    <th> Main Action Keywords </th>
                    <th> Sub Action Keywords </th>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <%
            for(int i =0; i<5;i++)
            {
            %>
            <form action = "Testing">
            <table style="width: 100%">
                <tr>
                    <td> Test <%= i %> </td>
                    <td> 
                        <div>
                            <select name = "Actions" class = "Actions" >
                                <%
                                for(int j=0;j<4;j++)
                                {
                                %>
                                <option value="Action<%= j %>">
                                    Action <%= j %>
                                </option>
                                <%
                                }
                                %>
                            </select>
                        </div>  
                    </td>
                    <td> 
                        <select name = "SubActions" class = "SubActions" multiple>
                            <%
                            for(int k=0;k<4;k++)
                            {
                            %>
                            <option value="SubAction<%= k %>">
                                Sub Action <%= k %>
                            </option>
                            <%
                            }
                            %>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <%
            } 
            %>
            <br><br>
            <input type = submit value = "Submit" name ="submit" />
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jquery chosen utils/chosen.jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jquery chosen utils/prism.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $(".Actions").chosen({
                width: "75%"
            });
            $(".SubActions").chosen({
                width: "75%"
            });
        });
    </script>
</html>
```

I want my Testing.java to be something like this:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

@WebServlet("/Testing")
public class Testing extends HttpServlet
{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException 
{


    String a = request.getParameter("Actions"); //Should get actions corrsponding to each test 
    String b = request.getParameter("SubActions"); //Should get subactions corrsponding to each test


   }   
}
```

Current Testing.java only returns the action and first sub action of the first row(Test 0).
I'm mostly using HTML with a little jQuery for the dropdowns.

Can anyone give me suggestions on how to do the same?

Comment: I would suggest use Bootstrap library for your page to make it more simple and clean way and in which you can use following dropdowns in your form:
[link](https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/examples/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a way to access each action and sub-action using Shantaram's idea though it's not totally correct.

So refining his idea, I made the following changes:

```
<select name = "Actions[<%= i %>]" class = "Actions" >
```

and

```
<select name = "SubActions[<%= i %>]" class = "SubActions" multiple>
```

For me, the following did not work:

```
String actions[] = request.getParameterValues("Actions");
```

For accessing them, I did the following:

```
String actions[] = new String[5];
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        actions[i] = request.getParameter("Actions["+i+"]");

String[][] subActions = new String[5][];
    for (i = 0; i < length; i++) 
        subActions[i] = request.getParameterValues("SubActions["+i+"]");
```

Any better way is most welcome.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is `Array` for **Actions** and `2D Array` for **Sub Actions**:

For Sub Actions Also

Change:
`<select name = "SubActions" class = "SubActions" multiple>`
to:
`<select name = "SubActions[<%= i %>]" class = "SubActions" multiple>`

And To Access Values in Servlet Do this:

```
String[] actions =request.getParameterValues('Actions');
int length = 5 ;       // Length of Rows
String[][] subActions = new String[length][];

for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    subActions[i] = request.getParameterValues("SubActions["+i+"]");
}
```

I can see yor Loop of **5** for creating rows so it is Fixed.
If Your Rows(**Selects**) are **Dynamic/Growable** In **Servlet** you need to access it Dynamic way. Then Change length dynamically in Servlet:

```
int length = 0 ;       // Length of Rows
if( actions != null )
    length = actions.length;     // Calculate Rows Dynamic
```

Comment: I liked the idea you suggested. However, the use of the variable _j_ seems to be wrong as it will always be 4 when used in the subaction select attribute.

Comment: Okay I found my mistake, will update soon thanxs for noticed

Comment: I removed `j`, and updated corresponding `subActions[i] = request.getParameterValues("SubActions["+i+"]");`

Comment: are you getting all selected `actions` ? coz I think no need of this `Actions[<%= i %>]`, plz check and let me know, So I can edit this

Comment: Your answer has some glitches that did not work for me.